# Deleting and adding users in a custom role, DNN portal

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am on DNN 4.7.0. I would like to delete all users who are in one of my custom roles and add new ones. Is there a way I can do this without deleting and adding users one by one? Are these users saved somewhere in the database where I could just run delete and insert statements?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User/Role Relationship is in the UserRoles table. You could write SQL against that table to insert the new relationship, and remove the old.

On a side note: I would highly encourage you to check out a newer version of DNN 4.7 is rather dated, buggy, and has security issues.